# CDI Injection in a Wildfly application

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi, wildfly

I've written an `HttpServlet` which gets deployed to a Wildfly container in a WAR file. The servlet looks like this:

```
 public class MyCallback extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    @Any
    private Event<MyEvent> event;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String eventName = request.getParameter("EVENT_NAME");
        MyEvent e = new MyEvent(eventName);
        event.fire(e);
    }
}
```

I also created a `beans.xml` file (as detailed [here](http://blog.frankel.ch/cdi-an-overview-part-1)) and placed it in my `WEB-INF` directory.  Unfortunately, I still get a `NullPointerException` when the code tries to execute the `event.fire(e)` line, which suggests to me the injection isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding at least one CDI bean (it doesn't have to do anything), e.g.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class JustABean { }
```

I had similar issue on Wildfly beta, it seems without a single "normal" bean CDI engine just wouldn't kick in.
Also Wildfly ships CDI 1.1 where beans.xml is optional.

Comment: Just checked it and it works. Take a look at this [Wildfly quickstart CDI example](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/cdi-injection).
That's a simple project with all the necessary setup and packaging, a good starting point.

Comment: Updated tutorial link: https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/8.x/cdi-injection